Behavior of the NotIn operator in Kubernetes PodAffinity versus the In operator in PodAntiAffinity
Does setting the following podAffinity on Deployment in Kubernetes:
podAffinity:
  requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
  - labelSelector:
      matchExpressions:
      - key: app
        operator: NotIn
        values:
        - myapp
    topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"

have the same effect as setting the following antiAffinity?
podAntiAffinity:
  requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
  - labelSelector:
      matchExpressions:
      - key: app
        operator: In
        values:
        - myapp
    topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"


Refer to this kubernetes documentation on Affinity and anti-affinity and also go through this document which might be helpful for you.

Do you know the answer then?

I have summarized all answers + added hands-on example using k3d here: https://zablo.net/blog/post/kubernetes-pod-affinity-notin-podantiaffinity-in-operators/

No, though they might seem similar, setting the podAffinity with the NotIn or In operator are not the same.
PodAffinity with NotIn means that the pods are placed on nodes where no other pods with the label app: myapp are running. So it's kind of like saying, "put me where these other guys aren't."
PodAntiAffinity with In is the opposite; it makes sure that the pods aren't scheduled on nodes where there are pods with the label app: myapp. It's more like, "keep me away from these other guys."
Kubernetes documentation provides detailed explanations of affinity and anti-affinity rules.
ref: Affinity and anti-affinity

The first statement asserts that you can schedule a pod on a node only if there are pods scheduled on that node with the label app different from myapp, and the second statement asserts that you cannot schedule a pod on a node if there is some pod on the same node with the label app equal to myapp, so they are different. If there is no pod with label app on the node, the first statement does not allow scheduling, whereas the second one allows scheduling.
Pay attention because, if no pod matches an affinity stetement, kubernetes checks if the pod itself matches, and if so, the pod is scheduled, so the affinity rule might change behaviour in different situations. Moreover in the statements there is no namespace selection, so the rules apply only to the namespace of the pod where the affinity/anti-affinity definition appears.
